# Can't create Spring Data Event Listener in Kotlin

Tags: java, spring, spring-data, kotlin, spring-data-neo4j-4

I tried creating an event listener like this:

```
@Bean
open fun beforeSaveEventApplicationListener(): ApplicationListener<BeforeSaveEvent>
{
   return ApplicationListener<BeforeSaveEvent>()
   {
       fun onApplicationEvent(event: BeforeSaveEvent)
       {
           //Do something with event
       }
   }
}
```

. . . but it won't compile. Where the generic type is specified, the compiler returns:

```
Type argument expected
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It would help if you can show the declaration line of the ApplicationListener class/interface.

Comment: Jasper, I found the problem:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/34646925/3679676

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that there are a few possible `BeforeSaveEvent` classes you could be using.  Here are some of the Spring classes mocked out to show you the difference (*pay attention to the two `BeforeSaveEvent` declarations*):

```
open class ApplicationEvent(source: Any): EventObject(source) {}

interface ApplicationListener<T: ApplicationEvent> {
    fun onApplicationEvent(event: T)
}

// the Spring Data Neo4j version requires a type
class BeforeSaveEvent<T>(source: Any, val entity: T): ApplicationEvent(source) {}

// the Spring data version does not
class BeforeSaveEvent(source: Any): ApplicationEvent(source) {}
```

And so if you code to the Spring data version, your code would be this:

```
open class Something {
    open fun beforeSaveEventApplicationListener(): ApplicationListener<BeforeSaveEvent> {
        return object : ApplicationListener<BeforeSaveEvent> {
            override fun onApplicationEvent(event: BeforeSaveEvent) {
                //Do something with event
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If you code to the Neo4j version (which I think you are, because your tags for your question include `spring-data-neo4j-4`), you have to also specify the entity type parameter:

```
class MyEntity {}

open class Something {
    open fun beforeSaveEventApplicationListener(): ApplicationListener<BeforeSaveEvent<MyEntity>> {
        return object : ApplicationListener<BeforeSaveEvent<MyEntity>> {
            override fun onApplicationEvent(event: BeforeSaveEvent<MyEntity>) {
                //Do something with event
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So you see exactly what the compiler was asking for:

> Please give me a type parameter for `BeforeSaveEvent` because it is really `BeforeSaveEvent<T>`

It could be that you imported the wrong class and mean the other `BeforeSaveEvent` or you imported the correct `BeforeSaveEvent<T>` and didn't adapt to its actual generic type parameter needs.

Also since `ApplicationListener` is an interface you don't want `()` after its use because that means you are trying to call a constructor on an interface.

***NOTE:*** *it helps in your questions to provide the declaration signatures of relative classes, from the IDE's perspective (have it click through to find the class you are using, it might not be the one you think you are).*

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you wanted to achieve, but a simple fix would be to add the `object` keyword in the returning statement:

```
@Bean 
open fun beforeSaveEventApplicationListener(): ApplicationListener<BeforeSaveEvent> 
{
    return object : ApplicationListener<BeforeSaveEvent>()
    {
        override fun onApplicationEvent(event: BeforeSaveEvent)
        {
            //Do something with event
        }
    }
}
```

`object` means that you return an object of that class, not a sttrange thing that was in your code. Also I added `override` since I suspect that `onApplicationEvent` is a method of `ApplicationListener`, so it must be overridden.

Actually, if it's ok with you to have only one such an object, you can use  `object` as a singleton dirrectly:

```
@Bean object beforeSaveEventApplicationListener: ApplicationListener<BeforeSaveEvent>() {
    override fun onApplicationEvent(event: BeforeSaveEvent) {
            //Do something with event
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the info, but it still won't compile - at `BeforeSaveEvent` compiler reports 'type argument expected'. The equivalent Java code works fine - I just want to hook save of a neo4j node to allocate a UUID. Could it be a Kotlin compiler issue? I think I'll report it to Jetbrains.

Comment: I think the API wants an instance of BeforeSaveEvent to be passed to the constructor invocation

Comment: The issue is you don't know the declaration of `BeforeSaveEvent`, and the compiler is telling you that it has a generic type parameter.  But the code does not provide one.  I wrote the details in another answer.

Comment: `ApplicationListener` is an interface, not a class.  it shouldn't have `()` after it for calling a constructor.